# How to set alarm using shared preferences in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I have a alarm manager to set alarm. Works fine when the phone is on. But the problem is for example(i will set alarm on 10, 10.30, 10.40) and i will power off the phone. after some time i will power on the phone, alarms are not ringing.So i used boot receiver class, But i will ring alarm for only first alarm 10 o'clock. Rest of the alarms are cancelled. How to set alarm for rest of the alarms. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste your code. As always, with the `AlarmManager`, `Log` a `SimpleDateFormat` to confirm that you are actually setting it to what to what you think you are. If you've added

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

To your `receiver` in the `manifest`, then it should work.

Comment: invoke alarm                                                   public void invokeAlaram(long invokeTime, long rowId)
 {
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
  Intent i =  new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
  i.putExtra("rowId", String.valueOf(rowId));
  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, invokeTime, PendingIntent.getService(this , (int) System.currentTimeMillis() ,i , 0));

 }  @LuxaryMode